# $ionicLoading not shown well in some versions of android

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, preloader

I have a $ionicloading (preload), and this is my code:

```
$ionicLoading.show({
    template: '<ion-spinner icon="lines" />',  
    animation: 'fade-in',
    showBackdrop: true,
    maxWidth: 200,
    showDelay: 0
  });
```

when I run this in the desktop version is perfect, also it looks good on some devices. but in other preload indicator that it will not appear in the middle. I do not know what it could be. What could I do?. thank you.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGvzzV

Comment: please show us your code on codepen as that : http://codepen.io/ionic/

Comment: @Microsmsm ok, is this.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGvzzV

Comment: try now ??
http://codepen.io/Microsmsm/pen/GoLMyW

Comment: @Microsmsm Why you did it again ?. The problem is only seen on mobile. in the desktop version is fine..

Comment: what devices does it work on and what devices does it not work on? Do these devices have the same OS etc?

Comment: @Will.Harris the problem is with not so new devices.

Comment: Can you be more specific... if its Android what version? 4.4 or 5.0 or older than 4.4. I ask because there could be some CSS used by Ionic which is not supported in an older version or doesn't work as intended

Comment: @Will.Harris for example in a device with version 4.2.1 the preload does not appear. gray background appear, but the indicator does not appear.

Comment: I'd take a guess at the webview in 4.2.1 not supporting something which explains why you get the grey background with no spinner. Unfortunately I can't be anymore helpful than this. So try researching `$ionicLoading` or `ion-spinner` and Android 4.2.1 issues

Comment: in 4.1.2 too the same problem :(

Comment: @Will.Harris there is not good information about this problem :(